# How to write a regex to match a set of comma-separated key:value pairs?

Tags: regex

Say i want to match such a repeated pattern:

```
a:b
a:b,c:d
```

So a `comma` separated subsequence pairs `s1:s2,s3:s4,....` (no trailing comma allowed), which each subsequence should be non-empty, and can include any ASCII char but not the separator: `,`, and must match the whole string.

In this case how the rust regexp will look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase the pattern as:

```regex
[^:,]+:[^:,]+(?:,[^:,]+:[^:,]+)*
```

### Demo

Comment: thanks a lot, could u explain why better to exclude the `-` also from the subsequence left part? and for matching whole str i just need to prefix with `^` and suffix with `$` right?

Comment: @lnshi Sorry, the `-` were typos, and yes, to apply this pattern to the entire input just surround my answer with `^` and `$`.